# Program to read asynchronously in boost asio with C++11 future

Tags: c++11, boost-asio

In the recent development of my project have I used `std::future` with `async_read_some` so that caller, say user thread, can wait for specific duration on asynchronous I/O and appear like a synchronous procedure. But **call to get std::future object async_read_some function yields never returns in case that the remote connecting peer corrupts**. It seems that system error in asynchronous operation is not propagated as stated at all.

```
std::future<size_t> result=socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data, size), boost::asio::use_future);
std::future_status status=result.wait_for(std::chrono::millisecond(1000));
switch(status){
    case std::future_status::ready:
        try{
        bytes=result.get(); /* never returns in case of peer disconnection */
        }catch(std::system_error & error){
            /* print something only if error is caught */
        }
        break;
    case std::future_status::timeout:
        ...
    case std::future_status::deferred:
        ...
};
```

when program runs in according scenario, the process "sinks" - it appears exactly like there is deadlock in asio implementation. A trace stops in implementation of `std::future::get()`

```
/// Wait for the state to be ready and rethrow any stored exception
  __result_type
  _M_get_result() const
  {
    _State_base::_S_check(_M_state);
    _Result_base& __res = _M_state->wait();
    if (!(__res._M_error == 0))
  -->    rethrow_exception(__res._M_error);  <-- //deepest trace with available source
    return static_cast<__result_type>(__res);
  }
```

After investigating into documentation, I found very few words

> **`std::future<std::size_t> my_future = my_socket.async_read_some(my_buffer, boost::asio::use_future);`** The initiating function (async_read_some in the above example) returns a future that will receive the result of the operation. If the operation completes with an error_code indicating failure, it is converted into a system_error and passed back to the caller via the future.

However, there is NOTHING my program catches around `result.get()`.

`PS: linux 3.8.0-37-generic #53~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 19 21:39:14 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

Comment: "It seems that system error in asynchronous operation is not propagated as stated at all."
Internally asio use std::promise to create returned future. Asio do not introduce some magic asio-future stuff. This future must be in ready state to reach your try/catch block, it means that exception was set by asio or value was set by asio. So bug can't be there.
Check again you usage of this future object, possible you're doing some wrong operations with it.

Comment: @inkooboo Sorry the story may appear ambiguous to you but fact is, it returns fine only before remote peer corrupts. If someone can explain me how asio `converts system_error and pass back to the caller via future` that'll be helpful.

Comment: You can look into source code "boost/asio/impl/use_future.hpp" for more ideas.
When you pass `boost::asio::use_future` as a completion handler for `async_read_some`, asio creates object of `promise_handler` as a completion handler. The returned future is creating from its promise (see async_result class template specialization).
You could try to set breakpoints somewere in this file, and try to debug. May be it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing that in the thread that performs `io_service.run()`?
If yes then `std::future_status status=result.wait_for(std::chrono::millisecond(1000));` will block because no result can be received until the io_service returns to it's event loop to be able to check for new data there.
So using the `future` would only make sense if you access it from another thread (which can block while Boosts io_service can do the work).

If you want to do everything in the same thread you will be required to work in an asynchronous style, e.g. with the callbacks that are invoked when the operation completes.

Comment: I am checking future in another thread that polls in round robin style in time. So future is definitely the easiest to use in my case. Like I said, it'll be helpful if anyone could tell how should I do to handle error upon corruption of remote peer with future.