# (How) Can I get a callback on a boost::asio::io_service when a std::future is ready?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio, future

Suppose I have a library that allows to make asynchronous requests and returns a `std::future` to query the (state of the) result. I want to integrate that library with a `boost::asio::io_service` so that a callback is called in the `io_service` loop as soon as the future is ready. Is there any way to achieve that without changing the library or regularly polling the future in the io loop?

*Note: there are several questions that deal with the reverse problem, i.e. getting a `std::future` that is ready when some operation on the `io_service` completes (e.g. [Program to read asynchronously in boost asio with C++11 future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627382/program-to-read-asynchronously-in-boost-asio-with-c11-future)). I couldn't find  a way of achieving the exact opposite, i.e. getting a callback executed on the `io_service` when the `future` is ready.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `then` you can specify that something is to be executed when the future is ready:

```
future<T> my_future = lib::get_some_future();
my_future.then([] (future<T> f) {
    do_something_with_io_service(f.get())
}); // .then returns a new future (future<void> in this case) that allows chaining
```

Note however that `std::future` as of C++11 is missing a `then` member function. You could instead use [`boost::future`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.unique_future.then) or [implement it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14935704/2515282).

Answer (score 1):

How about spawning a daemon thread to do the job, like the following:

```
#include <future>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

template <class Callback, class T>
void post_when_ready(boost::asio::io_service& iosvc,
                     std::shared_ptr<std::future<T>> ptr,
                     Callback callback) {
  std::thread{
    [=, &iosvc] {
      ptr->wait();
      // ...
      iosvc.post(std::move(callback));
    }
  }.detach();
}
```